HTML Page can access SVGs from a folder, but cannot load them
I am currently making a game with HTML, and I set up a temporary page to test if something works. I am trying to have some SVG files from a folder put on my HTML site by putting in JavaScript:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SVG Gallery</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>SVG Gallery</h1>
    <div id="svg-container"></div>

    <script>
        async function fetchSVGs() {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('/assets/svg/props/items');
                const text = await response.text();
                
                // This will parse the directory listing to extract SVG file names.
                const parser = new DOMParser();
                const doc = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/html');
                const links = Array.from(doc.querySelectorAll('a'))
                    .filter(link => link.href.endsWith('.svg'));

                // Load each SVG file dynamically
                const container = document.getElementById('svg-container');
                links.forEach(link => {
                    const svgPath = link.getAttribute('href');
                    const img = document.createElement('img');
                    img.src = svgPath;
                    container.appendChild(img);
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error loading SVGs:', error);
            }
        }

        fetchSVGs();
    </script>
</body>
</html>

As you can see I want to list them all on the page. It did manage to enter the items folder and see all the items in it, but it couldn't load them. It said
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
Here are the items in my folder and the system accessing them but not loading the images:
enter image description here
enter image description here

How is your directory tree like? Specifically, which folder/subfolders do you have your HTML and SVG in?

"Can access but not load them" -> HTTP 404 Status: Request is understood but the requested resource could not be found. This means HTML could not access the file, at least not under this address. Look into the dev tools under the network tab. Then see which path it tries to use to access the image. It will differ from the actual path you're thinking about.

You need to prepend a suitable path depending on your html location. E.g "assets/svg/props/items"+svgPath . The directory listing html hrefs contain only the filenames itself ("apple.svg")

The error 404 usually occurs when the file path is wrong. Please check your file is correct. If your HTML file is in the root directory, ensure the assets/svg/props/items folder structure matches this.
If you have a known list of SVG filenames, you can use JavaScript to dynamically add  elements for each file.


<script>
        // List of SVG filenames
        const svgFiles = ['image1.svg', 'image2.svg', 'image3.svg'];
        const folderPath = '/assets/svg/props/items/';

        const container = document.getElementById('svg-container');
        svgFiles.forEach(file => {
            const img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = folderPath + file;
            img.alt = file;  // Optional alt attribute for accessibility
            container.appendChild(img);
        });
  
</script>




your suggestion of JS code is very unnecessary, this code is already in the post

This part is not used, the question uses fetch request to get the images.
